# SAS targed encored

Tags: sas

**Hi,
Can someone explain to me what a given code sequence does step by step?****

**I must describe it in detail what is happening in turn**

```
%macro frequency_encoding(dataset, var);
   proc sql noprint;
     create table freq as 
     select distinct(&var) as values, count(&var) as number
     from &dataset 
     group by Values ;

 create table new as  select *, round(freq.number/count(&var),00.01) As freq_encode  
from &dataset  left join freq    on &var=freq.values;
 quit;
 data new(drop=values number &var);
     set new;
     rename freq_encode=&var;
   run;
 data new;
     set new;
     keep &var;
   run;

data dane(drop = &var);
set dane;
run;

data dane;
set dane;
set new;
run;
```

Comment: Other than waste a lot of time doing things in two or three steps that could be done in one?

Comment: Your posted only part of a program. You have the beginning of a macro definition, but not the end.  And there is no example call to the macro provided. Or sample data.

Comment: PROC FREQ is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL is first finding the frequency of each value of the variable. Then it divides those counts by the total number of non-missing values and rounds that percentage to two decimal places (or integers when you think of the ratio as a percentage).

This could be done in one step with:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table new as 
  select *,round(number/count(&var),0.01) as freq_encode
  from (select *,&var as values,count(&var) as number
          from &dataset
          group by &var
        )
  ;
quit;
```

It is not clear what the DANE dataset is supposed to be. If &DATESET does not equal DANE then those last four data steps make no sense.  If it does then it is a convoluted way to replace the original variable with the percentage.

The first one is basically trying to rename the calculated percentage as the original variable and eliminate the original variable and the other two intermediate variables used in calculating the percentage.

The second one is dropping all of the variables except the new percentage.

The third one is dropping the original variable from "dane".

The last one is adding the new variable back to "dane".

Assuming DANE should be replaced with &DATASET then those four data steps could be reduced to one:

```
data &dataset;
  set &dataset(drop=&var);
  set new(keep=freq_encode rename=(freq_encode=&var));
run;
```

It is probably best not to overwrite your original dataset in that way.  So perhaps you should add an OUT parameter to your macro to name to new dataset you want to create.

You could have avoided all of those data steps by just adding the DROP= and RENAME= dataset options to the dataset generated by the SQL query.

So perhaps you want something like this:

```
%macro frequency_encoding(dataset, var,out);
proc sql noprint;
  create table &out(drop=&var number rename=(freq_encode=&var)) as 
  select *,round(number/count(&var),0.01) as freq_encode
  from (select *,count(&var) as number
          from &dataset
          group by &var
        )
  ;
quit;
%mend ;

%frequency_encoding(sashelp.class,sex,work.class);
```